# MVC Required validation attribute in different circumstances

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, class, requiredfieldvalidator

Let's suppose we have a class *Client*:

```
  public class Client
  {
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int Type { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string County { get; set; }
    public string Town { get; set; }
    public string PostalCode { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }

    public string StudentName { get; set; }
    public string Birthdate { get; set; }

    public string Company { get; set; }

    public string Observations { get; set; }
   }
```

The type (field *Type*) of the client can be 1(person) or 2(company).

How can I add different required attributes for both cases?

I want for the first case (person) to have required attributes for the following fields: ID , TYPE, *Name*, Address and Email.

For the second case (company) I want to add required attributes for: ID , TYPE, *StudentName*, Address,*Company* and Email.

How can I do this?

Comment: FluentValidation is a nice library for complex (and simple) validation : http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/ You would have a `Rulefor(m => m.SudentName).NotEmpty().When(m => m.Type == <TypeCompany>);` for example.

Comment: The class `Client` should be a base class. You should create `Person` and `Company` classes which derives from base class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a library called "MVC Foolproof Validation" for this:
http://foolproof.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

This could be something like this:

```
class Client
{
    [Required]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Address { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string Town { get; set; }
    public string PostalCode { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Birthdate { get; set; }
    public string Observations { get; set; }
}

class Person : Client
{
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

class Company : Client
{
    [Required]
    public string StudentName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Company { get; set; }

}
```

Btw you answered yourself: "I want person", "I want company" - this states that you want 2 different classes for this not a single one.